# Android/Java: convert UTF-8 to UTF-16

Tags: java, android, json, unicode, encoding

I am developing Android App and I need to communicate to local server via TCP/IP. We used JSON (I'm using Jackson parser for Android) to pass the message to the server.

When I do ***ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes()*** using jackson it produces bytes in UTF-8? Our local server is written in C# .NET and the uses UTF-16 Little Endian encoding.

When the bytes arrived at the server, it unable to parse the JSON. When I debug the server by convert the json byte to string, I can see some part of the string are scrambled. I suspect because of this UTF-8 to UTF-16 Little Endian problem.

My question is, how do I convert these json bytes that is in **UTF-8** to **UTF-16 Little Endian** before I pass it to the server.

Thanks

Comment: I'd change the server.  First off, the default for anything going over a network is network bye order.  Network byte order is big-endian, not little.  Secondly, utf-8 is the standard for passing string data around a network.  UTF-16 is very abnormal, and tends to only be used by older languages that were created in the days they thought 2 bytes would be enough to hold any character in the world.  If you need to use utf-16 internally, I would convert it at the input stage, and convert back to utf-8 at output.

Comment: Print the bytes as hex values not text string (then show a small sample here, especially with scrambled part included to compare bytes of normal vs scrambled)... It's possible your conversion is simply making a scramble of non-alphabetic characters. **For a faster Answer** : Make an example JSON (show it) and then show how same JSON bytes look (scrambled etc) for advice. I doubt is UTF-8/16 issue though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
byte[] utf8bytes = .......
byte[] utf16bytes = (new String(utf8bytes, "utf-8")).getBytes("utf-16");
```

Untested.

You can try UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE for little and big endian.

Comment: the encoding works fine! thanks. it turn out it wasn't a problem with encoding. something wrong with the encryption. thanks for your code. it helps me to verify that the problem wasn't with the encoding. thanks!